# angular 13 what is module is causing this?

Tags: asp.net, angular, typescript

I have an ASP.Net MVC project with Angular 13 (upgraded from 8).

v13 is giving me this issue:

```
core.mjs:4078 JIT compilation failed for NgModule class AppModule {}

core.mjs:4097 Uncaught Error: The NgModule 'AppModule' needs to be compiled using the JIT compiler, but '@angular/compiler' is not available.
```

I believe that the project is "Lazy Loading" the components:

```
  {
    path: 'admin',
    loadChildren: async () => await import('./ADMIN/admin.module').then(m => m.AdminModule),
    canActivate: [AdminEntitlementGuard]
  },
```

I have stripped out a lot of dependencies that are old and don't have IVY updates.

I'm just at a loss for this `core.mjs` reference and what I need to do to fix it.  I've looked at many of the questions here regarding this error, but none of the solutions have worked.  Including updating my `package.json` file:

```
"postinstall": "ngcc --properties es2015 browser module main --first-only --create-ivy-entry-points"
```

I've done an **npm update**, I've remove the **node_modules** folder and done an **npm install** (many times) as well as restarted VS Code (many times).

The one thing that I haven't done, is to set **enableIvy=false** - which I'm not wanting to do.  I want this to work with Ivy.

Is it because of the lazy loading?
Do I need to remove every non **@angular** dependency to get this to function

I'm really trying to get to the bottom of this so I can rebuild the application if necessary.  But I need to know what the core issue.  Unfortunately this error message isn't telling me what to fix (at least in my current understanding).

Let me know what you need to see.  I have to be careful with copy/pasting code.

Comment: Do you create somehow components dynamically ?

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler - Can you point me to an example of how that is currently done?  (I'm not sure TBH).  I didn't write this project originally.

Comment: Something that calls `createComponent `.

Comment: The only thing that I've found with "createComponent" is the vendor.js file that gets generated on ng build - which BTW I'm not sure how or why that file gets created either.

Comment: Is the lazy loading done correctly? AFAIK it should be without the async and await. you can change it like this `async () => (await import('./ADMIN/admin.module')).AdminModule` or `loadChildren: () => import('./ADMIN/admin.module').then(m => m.AdminModule)`